# Basic question crossing two categorical fields on the same population

Tags: categorical-data

I am new to the subject and I assume that my question is basic...
I have two sets of aggregated data on a population (not a sample)
both data sets are categorical data:
let's say I have age groups such as:
0-17, 18-35, 36-50, 50-65, 65+
and another group of relations:
lawyer, son of a lawyer, spouse of a lawyer, grandchild of a lawyer ex.

keep in mind that I only have the aggregated data - so I only know how many are in each group and I know that the population in hand is the same!
can I tell if there is a correlation between the two sets? how strong it is and in what direction? I can get to the p-value of the crossing of each field I think (say the p-value of the population that is 0-17 and grandchildren) but what would be the next steps?

thank you so much!!!

Comment: my hypothesis is that if one belongs to the youngest category he has a higher chance of being a grandchild, but how do I prove that or that there is a high probability of that being true...

Comment: perhaps a simulation model would solve this?

Comment: How would you define correlation for a categorical variable? Categories like "son of the lawyer" and "spouse of a lawyer" do not have obvious ordering so it'd be hard to define what is meant by them co-relating.